# Mirrors for Laravel Homestead Box

Tags: laravel, vagrant, homestead

I got a new machine and have to download the homestead box again. But it seems that the server it is hosted on is painfully slow at the moment (http://cabinet.laravel.com/homestead-0.2.1.box). 
Are there any mirrors, where i can download the box a little bit faster?

Answer (score -1):

https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead?page=2 is where I download mine from.

Comment: From the looks of it off laravel and vagrantcloud are the same thing. The box is self hosted. vagrantcloud simply redirects. https://vagrantcloud.com/laravel/boxes/homestead/versions/0.2.2/providers/virtualbox.box -> HTTP 302 -> http://cabinet.laravel.com/homestead-0-2-2.box